# Magento2 - Get Price without "price-details" AKA Tax

Tags: magento2, product, price, template

How can I get the price for a product WITHOUT any TAX / Shipping Details?

Currently it is `echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type);` and gives out price + price-details (tax etc).

**Is there a easy way how to get price without price-details?**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can simply do:

```
echo $_item->getPrice();
```

Comment: Hmm, but then it isnt formatted correctly.. and sometimes gives out a "0"...